# Adding a loading gif when submitting form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

While my code calculates, Id like the submit button to go from the "RUN" that it is now to the loading gif that I have.  Now when I click the RUN button, I also need a certain script to run which calculates all sorts of data and returns it back to the page.  I wrote a  function that holds the other two function and calls them in sequence.  I even added a 3rd function that would revert back the submit button but I can't seem to figure this out.

The website is www.fsaesim.com/simulation.html which would be much easier to see the code, however attached is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="framework.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowCalculation() {
        var results = Main($("#vehicleWeightTxt").val(), $("#tireChoiceSel").val(), $("#wheelBaseTxt").val(), $("#wheelRadiusTxt").val(), $("#trackWidthTxt").val(), $("#hcgTxt").val(), $("#weightDistributionTxt").val(), $("#shiftRpmTxt").val(), $("#ntTxt").val());

        $('#outputTotalTime').empty();
        $('#outputTotalPoints').empty();
        $('#outputFuelUsed').empty();
        $('#outputTimeOpenThrottle').empty();
        $('#outputCorneringTimeTotal').empty();
        $('#outputTotalStraightSectionTime').empty();
        $('#outputTotalNumberOfShifts').empty();
        $('#outputTractionLimitedDuration').empty();
        $('#outputMeanLongAccel').empty();
        $('#outputMeanHorsepower').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationTime').empty();
        $('#outputMeanAccelerationLongAccel').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationTractionLimitedTime').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationTotalPoints').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationWideOpenThrottlePercentage').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationShifts').empty();
        $('#outputAccelerationTrapSpeed').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEnduranceTime').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEndurancePoints').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEnduranceFuelUsed').empty();
        $('#outputTotalWOTPercentage').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEnduranceShifts').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEnduranceTractionLimitedTime').empty();
        $('#outputTotalEnduranceAcceleration').empty();
        $('#outputSkidpadTime').empty();
        $('#outputSkidpadPoints').empty();
        $('#outputSkidpadVelocity').empty();
        $('#outputSkidpadAcceleration').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossTime').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossPoints').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossTotalShifts').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossTractionLimitedTime').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossVelocity').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossWOTPercentage').empty();
        $('#outputAutocrossLongitudinalAcceleration').empty();
        $('#outputMaxHorsepower').empty();




        $("#outputTotalTime").append(results.output1);
        $("#outputTotalPoints").append(results.output2);
        $("#outputFuelUsed").append(results.output3);
        $("#outputTimeOpenThrottle").append(results.output4);
        $("#outputCorneringTimeTotal").append(results.output5);
        $("#outputTotalStraightSectionTime").append(results.output6);
        $("#outputTotalNumberOfShifts").append(results.output7);
        $("#outputTractionLimitedDuration").append(results.output8);
        $("#outputMeanLongAccel").append(results.output9);
        $("#outputMeanHorsepower").append(results.output10);
        $("#outputMaxHorsepower").append(results.output27);


        $("#outputAccelerationTime").append(results.output11);
        $("#outputMeanAccelerationLongAccel").append(results.output12);
        $("#outputAccelerationTractionLimitedTime").append(results.output13);
        $("#outputAccelerationTotalPoints").append(results.output14);
        $("#outputAccelerationWideOpenThrottlePercentage").append(results.output15);
        $("#outputAccelerationShifts").append(results.output16);
        $("#outputAccelerationTrapSpeed").append(results.output17);

        $("#outputTotalEnduranceTime").append(results.output1);
        $("#outputTotalEndurancePoints").append(results.output2);
        $("#outputTotalEnduranceFuelUsed").append(results.output3);
        $("#outputTotalWOTPercentage").append(results.output4);
        $("#outputTotalEnduranceShifts").append(results.output7);
        $("#outputTotalEnduranceTractionLimitedTime").append(results.output8);
        $("#outputTotalEnduranceAcceleration").append(results.output9);

        $("#outputSkidpadTime").append(results.output18);
        $("#outputSkidpadPoints").append(results.output19);
        $("#outputSkidpadVelocity").append(results.output20);
        $("#outputSkidpadAcceleration").append(results.output21);

        $("#outputAutocrossTime").append(results.output22);
        $("#outputAutocrossPoints").append(results.output23);
        $("#outputAutocrossTotalShifts").append(results.output24);
        $("#outputAutocrossTractionLimitedTime").append(results.output25);
        $("#outputAutocrossVelocity").append(results.output26);
        $("#outputAutocrossWOTPercentage").append(results.output4);
        $("#outputAutocrossLongitudinalAcceleration").append(results.output9);



    }
    function mouseClick() {
        document.getElementById("submitButton").src = "images/loading.gif";

    }
    function revertBack() {
        document.getElementById("submitButton").src = "images/simulationSubmit.png";
    }
    function simulationEvents() {
        mouseClick();
        ShowCalculation();
        revertBack();
    }


</script>

<center><a href=""><img src="images/simulationSubmit.png" alt="" id="submitButton" onmouseover="mouseOver()" onmouseout="mouseOut()" onclick="simulationEvents(); return false;" /></a></center>
```

Comment: If this isn't possible, id even be fine with writing it to the page right below the submit button.

Comment: Seems like once it starts to run the Javascript code, the page more or less freezes until it returns the value.

Comment: I think without like ASP.net or PHP I don't think its possible to do what I want, because the gif's freeze until the Javascript is done.  

Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your processing is being done in javascript, that will tie up your script until it finishes.

Javascript isn't multithreaded, it does one task at a time until that task is done.

Generally, when you see that animated gif while a form is being processed the page is using AJAX or something similar.  The number crunching is happening server-side using PHP or Python or something like that.

The animation just runs while the javascript waits to hear back from the server-side script.

You might be able to work around it somewhat with [this tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/multi-threading-javascript/) but that seems like overkill for this situation.  The easiest thing would probably be to send the form data to a server-side script or just deal with not having an animation during processing.

Edit: If you're wanting to learn how to do AJAX, [here's a tutorial](http://trevordavis.net/blog/ajax-forms-with-jquery) that uses jQuery, which your site is already loading.

Comment: Will do man, I figured as much after playing around with it for about an hour.  Thanks for the links to the tutorials!